# How to write better answers

Tags: discussion, answers

As a Stack Overflow user, I find many answers unreliable or outdated. It has been bugging me for a long time and prompted to change my own answering behavior. After some time I was able to compile a short list of rules which I am trying to follow: [How to answer programming questions online](https://phpdelusions.net/socode).

I would like to get some feedback for this list, is it good or bad for you, what could be improved or replaced (but not added, as I believe that 7 is the maximum number if you want people to read). Here it goes:

There is one thing that people participating on Stack Overflow often do not realize:

> When answering, one is helping not only the user who asked a question, but also thousands other people who will come from Google search later.

While everyone is trying to fulfill the wishes of the particular OP, the numbers are against them: the OP will forget this question the next day, while other people will keep coming for years.

So in the light of this simple equation, one can formulate the basic principles for answering.

1. Before answering, look for a duplicate. Most likely this question has been answered already and it's better to link an existing answer than to write another one.
2. Perform a *sanity check* for the question. People make strange assumptions and draw even stranger conclusions. Always verify the claimed behavior against your knowledge. If you don't have enough knowledge in the area, then don't answer at all, but wait for more experienced users to come.

   - think one move ahead: what would be the outcome of my answer? Will it do any good for the OP? May be it would contradict with some good practices or common sense?
   - think one move behind: why would the OP ask such a question? What could be the background? Isn't a question being an XY problem? If so, what could be the actual problem instead?
3. Do not answer using guesswork. Avoid blunt suggestions like "a file cannot be saved? check permissions!". There are thousands possible reasons for such a problem. Even if your suggestion will work for the OP, there are others for whom it won't. First tell a user how they can get the error message that will reveal the actual problem, and after that offer them the solution for this particular issue. Consider editing the question to include the error message to help future visitors quickly identify whether the question applies to their case.
4. When answering, always prefer a generalized solution for the problem stated in the question title, as Google will send people from Search based on the title.

   - Only after offering a generalized solution, add a section for the OP's problem. It will help them but not at the cost of distracting the future visitors.
   - Refrain from nitpicking, and do not make your answer a lengthy irrelevant code review. It will distract a future reader from the core problem's solution. If a code review is all you can offer then don't answer at all, instead vote to close the question as it is off topic - it may be better suited to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).
   - In case the question title is not relevant to the body, or not informative at all, edit the question title. It should be relevant to the problem and unique enough. As a result, it will attract more visitors and bring you more upvotes.
5. Always offer the better solution, avoid quick and dirty hacks. Don't make Stack Overflow a dispenser of bad or outdated practices. Do not submit to low demands. Remember all those people who will learn from your answer.
6. Always keep handy a test bench, an environment for the chosen language, where you can test the code you are offering. It will save you from making typos and also from a shameful blunder in case the technology is not that familiar to you. In short, always test your code before posting - it is not as hard as it seems. For example, every PHP user has a local web-server with PHP and database installed. It does no harm to write your code in your favorite editor, then run it and only then paste it to the answer.

   - A hint: you can always use this bench to test the code posted in the question. Sometimes the OP claims that their seemingly working code doesn't work, so you can test and prove it. Otherwise, vote to close the question.
7. If you notice that some answer of yours is getting more attention than others (in other words it gets an upvote once in a while), revisit it regularly and keep it up to date. One good, refined and well-explained answer is better than a dozen of quick and dirty code-only snippets.

---

I would like to discuss:

- Are these or similar rules applied by you when answering?
- If you have a better/different rule, which one would you replace with yours?
- Do you think some of the rules are counter productive?
- Do you believe answer quality will go up when such rules are applied by answerers?

Comment: Way too long and not helpful when you want to boost your "ego points" score, therefore not helpful for 99% of the answerers. But I appreciate that you want to teach them to be better users :).

Comment: In any cases, testing OP's code is not sensibly possible. OP's are generally hopeless when it comes to describing a test environment/spec and, often, that environment cannot be usefully reproduced. File handling with no files given, SQL with no table metadata or example records, 'doesn't work' with no error-messages, clients with no servers, messages with no protocols etc. are all, unfortunately 'normal' for SO questions.  In general, the OP's should do the testing.

Comment: maybe this should be in a Q&A format instead of a single post..

Comment: @MartinJames In most cases if the OP tested their code there wouldn't be the question to begin with!

Comment: And if the question doesn't contain the necessary information, then the other user is responsible for flagging/voting to close, not for answering.

Comment: @Tom oh, I do, as fast as I can.  It's a daily game of Whac-A-Mole.

Comment: @George This gave me an idea. Maybe instead of trying to improve bad questions, we should isolate them instead. Introduce a "Bad quality" flag, and a "Pink glasses" option hiding these. Questions marked with "Bad quality" remain on the site, but yield no rep, neither to askers nor answerers (until fixed and conform to "How to ask" guidance). That would simplify rewiew queues. Once marked as "Bad quality", the asker with be displayed a message "This question does not meet all required criteria [here], please follow the checklist. Thanks"

Comment: @MartinJames, I don't test it every time, but sometimes it's really handy. That's why it's suggested as a hint, not a rule. I just find it handy. On the other hand, it just occurred to me that it's better to be removed, just for sake of brevity.

Comment: @user5226582 a brilliant idea, something like what I was thinking of myself

Comment: @user5226582 Good idea, although it won't affect the OP (as they don't care about rep most of the time only that the question get's answered) but the people that answer a lot of bad quality questions are just in it for the rep so it'd stop the answering and hopefully stop the OP from asking bad questions!

Comment: Shouldn't that list be in an answer here? You're answering the question in the question. An answer like: _"In my perspective, one should follow these guidelines"_

Comment: Move #5 to #1. Then repeat it 6 more times.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No need to remove it, I would simply soften the tone of point 6 by saying "You should always bla" rather than "Always bla". That says in words that it is advice rather than a rule. That is really splitting hairs though, the list is a beauty.

Comment: One thing that's missing: If OP has a problem with the code, don't simply post a correct code snippet. Explain why OP's solution will not work, so he can learn from that mistake.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I've written a little about writing good technical answers here: http://stiemannkj1.gitlab.io/technical-writing/#answers. It seems like we have a lot of overlap. I like your advice on not guessing and testing the code before posting it (although so many popular tags have the FGITW problem, so I doubt many people there will follow it). I prefer to use comments to make educated guesses (if I have one) and if the OP confirms that it works, I post it as an answer.

Comment: Related: **["answering technical questions helpfully" by Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/)**