# Isolating bad quality questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bad-questions

I mentioned this in comments of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359378/how-to-write-better-answers).

Maybe instead of trying to improve bad questions, we could isolate them instead?

- Introduce a "Bad quality" question flag and property.
- Introduce a "Pink glasses" option which hides all "Bad quality" questions.
- Questions marked with "Bad quality" remain on the site, but yield no rep, neither to askers nor answerers (until fixed and conform to "How to ask" guidance or some other check-list).
- Once a question is marked as "Bad quality", the asker will see a pinned message "This question does not meet all required criteria [here] (how to ask), please follow the checklist. Thanks"

This could solve several problems, for example:

- Making reviews less ambiguous. A question either meets the criteria or it doesn't, no need to edit or close (but still an option to). Hopefully this will release some pressure from "Unclear what you're asking"/"Too broad"/"opinion based" close flag queue. (Many of those flags expire, or perhaps just mine)

[@George](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2315360/george) commented:

> although it won't affect the OP (as they don't care about rep most of the time only that the question get's answered) but the people that answer a lot of bad quality questions are just in it for the rep so it'd stop the answering and hopefully stop the OP from asking bad questions!

We would carefully balance the "criteria list", perhaps by using a selection of existing bad/good questions and making sure that they pass (or don't) appropriately. Possibly, some not-as-good-but-useful questions should still be allowed.

**Edit:** It was mentioned multiple times that bad questions occasionally have good and useful answers. In that case, we could autoremove the question flag if any answer receives enough upvotes. Or only award rep to answers above a threshold.

Comment: We have downvotes for bad quality already. Nobody makes you read downvoted questions.

Comment: They still get answered, which encourages the behaviour.

Comment: Nobody is preventing you from downvoting the answers either.

Comment: That's not as effective. downvote + upvote is still a positive rep.

Comment: Ahh you want your opinion that an answer is not useful to outweigh the opinions of others that it is.

Comment: I didn't say that. But currently it's the other way around.

Comment: You want a _"Bad quality"_ flag that _negates __all__ upvotes_. So yes, you _are_ requesting that your opinion outweighs upvotes.

Comment: It wouldn't be a single person flagging.

Comment: Even if it took 5 flags, those 5 would outweigh 200 upvotes. My point is that you can't "disable" reputation gain from an answer, with flags. You _could_ increase the rep loss from downvotes, but meh...

Comment: This feature already exists.  The machine preselects questions that are of questionable quality and puts them in the Triage queue.  About half of all questions asked every day go into that queue.  It seems to do a pretty good job of it, given that I rarely ever see anything worthwhile in that queue.  What little is left over from that queue, combined with questions that get upvotes, is presented in the [new-nav] page.  You have to opt-in explicitly to see that page, edit your profile.  They are not doing a lot of bragging about it, it is pretty buggy and they gave up on making it better.

Comment: Assuming that the bad/good percentage is around 80/20 you would expect that downvotes/upvotes  for each user to be in the same range. Somehow much less down votes are casted.

Comment: @Cerbrus We could autoremove the question flag if any answer receives enough upvotes

Comment: Good answers don't make a _bad_ question good.

Comment: This wouldn't make it good. *Useful* perhaps. And just so that the answerer gets his earned rep.

Comment: So, if I answer a completely ridiculously crappy question with an exceptionally good answer, the question is suddenly useful? No. The question shouldn't have been answered in the first place.

Comment: If 200 people upvoted an answer, then I guess the question was useful after all.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of removing the question flag, only answers with vote count above threshold could be awarded rep.

Comment: Then what would be the point (added value) of that flag in the first place?

Comment: - Reducing close vote queue (questions will become "low quality" instead), - Encouraging aksers to ask better questions, (by encouraging answerers not to encourage poor quality questions), - Get more askers to read help pages (by notifying them that the question does not meet the criteria, and if they want it answered they better tick off all the boxes they can).

Comment: @Cerbrus _Good answers don't make a_ bad _question good._ - Agreed, OTOH we have a [gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) for exactly that.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser: that still doesn’t excuse answering...

Comment: @Cerbrus no, it doesn't, but it's somehow encouraged. Maybe we should get rid of that badge?

Comment: Encouraged? Not really. Rewarded, yea... There have been feature requests to remove it.

Answer (score 24):

That *"Bad quality"* button already exists:

[image]

Users answering questions with said *"Bad quality"* mark applied a couple of times, risk getting their answer marked as *"Bad quality"*, also.

Comment: The [Pink glasses](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A0..+is%3Aquestion) mode also exists by that logic.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I wouldn't exactly call that a "feature". That's just search doing its thing.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of options already exist to handle these things, which include:

1. Down-vote
2. Flag as *Should be Closed...*
3. Close Vote
4. Moderator Flag
5. Delete Vote

Similarly for answers, but often times it happens that a bad quality question yields a high quality answer. That helps OP and other users that come looking for a similar solution.

> Questions marked with "Bad quality" remain on the site, but yield no rep, neither to askers nor answerers

This is a very bad idea, users that answer put some efforts into coming up with a solution, sometimes it is a lot of effort. And even if the rep gain is not a goal to answer a question it is still feels good when get some reputation from answering questions.
This way people will stop answering questions, while waiting to be sure that the question is not marked as Low Quality or something.

Comment: `This way people will stop answering questions, while waiting to be sure that the question is not marked as Low Quality or something` Most people will be able to tell straight away.

Comment: @user5226582 But still there are alot of up and coming users, who are trying to make their way up by answering questions, and put a lot of efforts in their answers to make their answers stand out from others.  Which might not be able to tell the questions quality as such.

Comment: that's a good point.